# To support a custom authentication flow, is it best to extend from OncePerRequestFilter or AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

If I want to support a new/custom authorization scheme for spring-security, should I extend from `OncePerRequestFilter` like `BasicAuthorizationFilter` does? Or should I extend from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` like `UsernamePasswordTokenFilter` (and others) do? I suppose a different way of asking this question is why doesn't `BasicAuthorizationFilter` extend from `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`?

Answer (score 6):

If you want to implement custom authentication scheme then you should use `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` . It provides a method `attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` that can be used to write custom authentication logic.

Spring has provided strategies to go ahead with the different type of authentication schemes. So as following authentication filters:

1. `BasicAuthorizationFilter` for HTTP Basic Authorization header authentication.
2. `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` it can be used for any type of custom authentication scheme. So I think Spring has already provided `BasicAuthorizationFilter` just for not to reinvent the wheel.

For example - All of the following authentication implementations are the subclasses of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

- `OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (Spring OAuth2)
- `ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter` (Spring OAuth2)
- `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (Web login authentication)